# Formatting a profile in WordPress and civiCRM 5.52

Tags: wordpress, profile

I created a profile for signing up for our newsletter. Everything works fine but the format is terrible. The black backdrop is a matter of the WordPress theme but

1. I don't want the links in the menu at the top left. These must be generated by civiCRM since I have menus turned off in WordPress.
2. the SAVE and CANCEL button seem to be generated by civiCRM and I would like to center these.

Where in civiCRM do I find controls for 1 and 2 above?
[image: See screenshot below]

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM provides basic styling of forms, but it's up to you to style them to your satisfaction in your theme, child theme or custom plugin.

I can't see any "links in the menu at the top left" in your screenshot, so can't advise on that.